# Unable to unzip file .tar.gz on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, tar, unzip

Hello  I have a problem with the command: tar -xvzf. I want unzip the plugins that I just downloaded but I get this message. but before everything else I needed your help please.

tar (child): cannot connect to plugin: resolve failed

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: child returned status 128
tar: error is not recoverable: exiting now

i have downloaded plugin with this command:

```
wget https://docs.cacti.net/_media/plugin:monitor-v1.2-1.tgz
```

Now when i try to unzip it doesn't work.

```
tar -xvzf plugin:monitor-v1.2-1.tar.gz
```

or `tar -zxvf plugin:monitor-v1.2-1.tar.gz`

please help.

Comment: You can use `7z` also to extract the contents of the archive : `7z e plugin\:monitor-v1.2-1.tgz`

Answer (score 6):

Because of the `:` in the archive filename, `tar` thinks you are trying to extract an archive on a remote system - hence the message:

```
cannot connect to plugin: resolve failed
```

You can force it to treat the file as local by adding the `--force-local` option. From `man tar`:

> ```
>   --force-local
>           Archive file is local even if it has a colon.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Allways use tab to complete names in linux, if you do that, you can see that will be like this:

```
tar -xvzf plugin\:monitor-v1.2-1.tgz
```